# Utilizing an existing database connection in a function

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

In a file, I connect to the database (using PDO) and the resulting connection is called $db, so that queries I run would be something like

```
$db->query("SELECT money FROM bank_accounts");
```

However, if I put that line in a function, $db isn't defined so it doesn't work.

Obviously reconnecting to the database in each function isn't the best way to accomplish db calls in a function so how would I accomplish something like

```
function stealMoney($acctID) {
    $db->query("SELECT money FROM bank_accounts WHERE accountID = $acctID");
}
```

Comment: Dare I say it too loudly but make $db a global inside the function.

Comment: @DevlshOne To clarify, do you mean the original declaration would be in the function? And then it would be accessible both in the main document and in any functions?

Comment: The original declaration would be OUTSIDE the functions and then inside the function you just add the line `global $db;`

Comment: @DevlshOne Derp. I did that exact thing months ago and completely forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$db` in a function.

And its not defined in the function, so definitely, `$db` is inaccessible/undefined to the function body.

There are two ways to deal it:

1) Pass `$db` as an argument to the function.

So, the function body becomes:

```
function stealMoney($acctID, $db = NULL) {
 $db->query("SELECT money FROM bank_accounts WHERE accountID = $acctID");
}
```

And the function call:

`stealMoney($acctID, $db);`

2) Use `global`:
In this case, you can use `$db` as a [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

So, the function body becomes:

```
function stealMoney($acctID) {
 global $db;
 $db->query("SELECT money FROM bank_accounts WHERE accountID = $acctID");
```

So that, your function will read this variable from outside and can access it.

Comment: Downvoter, you are most welcome. I request you for the reason of downvoting.